# C# Retrieve data from a XLS

Tags: c#, excel

I have a class ParseXLS(string name, string driveLincence, string sex)

My .xls looks like :

> Name | Drive Licence | Sex
>
> A   -        Y        -   M
>
> B   -        N        -    F

I want to read a big .xls and put all this data inside my class.
To read my .xls i used :

```
OleDbDataReader reader;
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" +
xlsFilePath + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0");
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("select * from [sheet1$]", con);
con.Open();
```

But i don't know how to obtain a List or ObservableCollection..
I found many hard solutions, lot of code, and not clear for me, i hope someone can help me with an easy solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The question details suggest xls

Answer (score 1):

You can load the data into a `DataTable`:

```
var results = new DataTable();
using(var con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" 
    + xlsFilePath + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0"))
{
    var command = new OleDbCommand("select * from [sheet1$]", con);
    con.Open();

    var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);

    adapter.Fill(results);
}
```

And from there, loop through the results and use the data however you need to:

```
foreach(DataRow row in results)
{
    var name = row["name"].ToString();
    var driversLicense = row["Drive Licence"].ToString();
    var sex = row["Sex"].ToString();

    //Do what you need
}
```

An alternative is to use a 3rd party library like [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/).